# Backing up data of android app in phone directory

Tags: android

I actually created an android app, now I want to add an backup and restore option in that app. If I click on backup option all the data for that particular user including video, media etc need to be backup in .zip format and need to be saved in phone directory.

My question is whether I need to use BackupAgentHelper provided by Android API or is there some other way I can do it? if anyone can help it will be very useful..

Comment: You can use and do what you want. There are no obligations.

Comment: @greenapps So, I can use BackupAgentHelper to perform this operation. As I read the document on that and they only mentioned of backing up data to cloud. So, I am confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Backup or Key/Value Backup (by extending BackupAgentHelper). Or you can implement your own custom backup solution.

If you want to target Android versions 4,5 or API level 22 or below you need to use Key/Value Backup. If you target Android 6 and above you can use Auto Backup.

Differences between Auto Backup and Key/Value Backup:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Auto backup:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Key/value backup:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup.html